# Open Android Alarm With Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a quick question about alarm service android in flutter.
now I'm making a function to open the android alarm from flutter.
I have tried the "android alarm manager" plugin to solve my problem. but after trying to implement it, it turned out that it wasn't the plugin that I needed.

All I need to do is open the alarm from flutter, that's all.

It looks like this:

[image: alarm to open the alarm]

The condition when clicking the "set Alarm" button will immediately open the alarm application.

Thank you for the opportunity, I am very open with all opinions and answers.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

This might work https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/alarmclock

I have not tried it. But should work